# How to Display UITableView from Plist Without Sorting It

Tags: xcode, uitableview, plist

I have this Plist in my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Medical Info</key>
    <array>
        <string>Date of Birth</string>
        <string>Blood Type</string>
    </array>
    <key>Allergies</key>
    <array>
        <string>Drug</string>
    </array>
    <key>Medication</key>
    <array>
        <string>Drug</string>
    </array>
    <key>Conditions</key>
    <array>
        <string>Medical</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I display it, it sorts out differently like this:

[image: Table view]

How can I display my table from my plist as what is stored on the plist and without sorting? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`NSDictionary` is not ordered, so there is no guarantee that it'll be displayed as what you ordered in your plist. Unfortunately, you'll have to sort it if you're using dictionary. Change it to use array if you want it the same order as the data in your plist.

Comment: Another option is to put a sort key (int) for each value and then sort the dictionary on that key.

Comment: There is [good sample code in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000134-CJBCBGII). Check out the section "Sorting Dictionaries". I have to say though, that X Slash's answer is what you should try first.

Comment: I actually changed it to NSArray by doing this, NSMutableArray *array = [dict allKeys]; yet it still displays the same.